# Have I found a bug in DateComponentsFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatecomponentsformatter

In answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65148910/difference-between-two-dates-not-showing-seconds-in-swift/65149207#65149207) on how to create a "xxx <largest_time_units> ago" string based on comparing two dates, I wrote out a complete solution to the problem.

It involves using a `DateComponentsFormatter` with `maximumUnitCount` set to 1 and `unitsStyle`  set to `.full`. Here is the code to create the `DateComponentsFormatter`:

```
 var timeFormatter:DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let temp = DateComponentsFormatter()
    temp.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .weekOfMonth, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
    temp.maximumUnitCount = 1
    temp.unitsStyle = .full
    return temp
}()
```

Then I wrote a function that uses the DateComponentsFormatter to output "xxx units ago" strings:

```
//Use our DateComponentsFormatter to generate a string showing "n <units> ago" where units is the largest units of the difference
//Between the now date and the specified date in te past
func timefromDateToNow(_ pastDate: Date) -> String {
    if let output = timeFormatter.string(from: pastDate, to: now) {
        return output + " ago"
    } else {
        return "error"
    }
}
```

I calculate dates in the past with code like this:

```
let value = Double.random(in: min ... max)
let past = now.addingTimeInterval(value)
```

Strangely, for certain values of `value`, I'm getting the string "0 months ago". The value I was able to capture was `-408754.0`, which is about 4 days, 17 hours.

Why would calling `timeFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -408754.0), to: Date())` return a string of 0 months? It should display a result of "4 days"!

Comment: Without even having read this post I can tell you that `DateComponentsFormatter` has produced inconsistent, odd, and sometimes buggy (i.e. returning multiple components when limiting to 1) results for me for years. After reading this post, I've experienced this exact behavior as well.

Comment: @bsod have you filed bug reports for any such behavior?

Comment: No I haven’t unfortunately, I’m a bad developer

Comment: @DuncanC now you understand why I said that DCF is buggy.

Comment: An easy fix would be to use the time interval between the two dates `timeFormatter.string(from: Date().timeIntervalSince(pastDate))`

Comment: Darn, you've found the wormhole! (By the way, I got 5 days, not 4...)

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about that. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like RelativeDateTimeFormatter wouldn't work for the use-case in the question I linked. The asker only wanted the largest units, and RelativeDateTimeFormatter doesn't appear to have the ability to select the units.

Comment: Have any of you submitted a bug using the new Feedback Assistant App? I just tried it and I get an error trying to log in.

Comment: @DuncanC I managed to fix this "0 months" issue by removing `weekOfMonth` from the `allowedUnits` array!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a reference to how far long ago, consider `RelativeDateTimeFormatter`, e.g.

```
let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
formatter.dateTimeStyle = .named
formatter.unitsStyle = .spellOut
formatter.formattingContext = .beginningOfSentence

let date = Date()

let longTimeAgo = date.addingTimeInterval(-10_000_000)
print(formatter.localizedString(for: longTimeAgo, relativeTo: date)) // Three months ago

let veryLongTimeAgo = date.addingTimeInterval(-100_000_000)
print(formatter.localizedString(for: veryLongTimeAgo, relativeTo: date)) // Three years ago
```